# Setting border for D3 arc inner radius

Tags: d3.js, svg, border, stroke, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to implement a sunburst chart using D3 arc.

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(function (d) {
            return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x)));
        })
        .endAngle(function (d) {
            return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx)));
        })
        .innerRadius(function (d) {
            return isLevelOne ? 200 : Math.max(0, y(d.y));
        })
        .outerRadius(function (d) {
            return 300;
        });

    var g = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(partition.nodes(this.props.data))
        .enter().append("g");

    var path = g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
            return '#' + d.color;
        })
        .style("stroke", "#ffffff")
        .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
            return d.image ? '0px' : '1px';
        })

        .attr("opacity", function (d) {
            return d.name === '' || !d.children ? 0 : 1;
        })
        .style("display", function (d) {
            return d.name === '' || !d.children ? 'none' : 'block';
        })
        .attr('class', style.rect)
        .on("click", click)
        .on("mousemove", function (d) {
            if (d.name) {
                tooltip
                    .style("left", d3.event.pageX + 50 + "px")
                    .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
                    .style("display", "inline-block")
                    .html(!d.children ? '<span class="' + style.head + '">' + d.name + ': </span><span>' + d.description + '</span>' : '<span class="' + style.head + '">' + d.name + ': </span><span>' + d.fullName + '</span><br><span class="' + style.head + '">Budget: </span><span>' + numberToCurrencyFormatter(d.size.budget, 0) + '</span><br><span class="' + style.head + '"> Expense: </span><span>' + numberToCurrencyFormatter(d.size.expense, 0) + '</span>');
            }
        })
        .on("mouseout", function (d) { tooltip.style("display", "none"); });

    var text = g.append("text")
        .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dx", "0") // margin
        .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align

        .style("font-size", "15px")
        .style("display", function (d) {
            return d.name === '' || !d.children ? 'none' : 'block';
        })
        .style("fill", "#ffffff")
        .on("click", click)
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .on("mousemove", function (d) {
            if (d.name) {
                tooltip
                    .style("left", d3.event.pageX + 50 + "px")
                    .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
                    .style("display", "inline-block")
                    .html(!d.children ? '<span class="' + style.head + '">' + d.name + ': </span><span>' + d.description + '</span>' : '<span class="' + style.head + '">' + d.name + ': </span><span>' + d.fullName + '</span><br><span class="' + style.head + '">Budget: </span><span>' + numberToCurrencyFormatter(d.size.budget, 0) + '</span><br><span class="' + style.head + '"> Expense: </span><span>' + numberToCurrencyFormatter(d.size.expense, 0) + '</span>');
            }

        })
        .on("mouseout", function (d) { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })

    g.append("svg:image")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + computeImageRotation(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dx", "0") // margin
        .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
        .attr('width', 156)
        .attr('height', 156)
        .style("display", 'none')
        .attr("opacity", 0)
        .attr('class', style.rect)
        .on("click", imageClick)
        .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
            return d.image ? d.image : '';
        });
```

and this is what I get.
[image]

But I need to highlight the inner circle by applying a border.

I tried adding a stroke to the `path`. But it results in generating a border around the sunburst slices. Not just the inner radius.

Attaching the resulting image below.
[image]

My aim is to generate a border only around the inner circle.
This is the expected result.
[image]

Comment: At first glance, I would guess you either need to add a circle, or add CSS for the existing middle circle, if there is one. If you post the generated SVG code, that may help. However, I'm not very familiar with D3, so someone may have a more 'D3' solution.

Comment: make a running example of your code